# Is it possible to set a textview at the bottom of a scrollview in Android?

Tags: android, textview, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have got a layout that looks something like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_margin="10dp">

//Some content

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Now, is it possible to set a textview at the bottom of the scrollview? It should always stay at the bottom of the page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_above="@id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
         //Some content
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Your text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: are you sure about that `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` in a textview?

Comment: @user2426316 100 % i have tested it just now !

Answer (score 1):

You can put a `LinearLayout` with a vertical orientation as the root element and have the `ScrollView` and `TextView` be children.

```
<LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView>
    ...
    </ScrollView>
    <TextView ... />
</LinearLayout>
```